# I need to include a php page in my asp.net application using master pages is that possible?

Tags: php, asp.net, iframe, master-pages

I would like to use the master page for this particular php page- Could I for instance have an aspx page that uses said master page and within that page use an iframe that references the php page? would that work? Any advice?

Comment: Why not just use all PHP or all ASP?

Comment: @JustinWood The page contains a php script that is pretty extensive- if possible i'd like to keep the functionality while still using what i'm most familiar with (asp.net)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup, you can use an `iframe`:

`<iframe src="path/to/my/file.php"></iframe>`

You'd have to make sure php is installed and working with IIS, as well.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Justin, it would probably be a lot easier to just pick one language and stick with it.  IFrames can cause problems.  But short answer - yes, you can have an iframe in your master page that points to a PHP page.